# confirm event within click event returned error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('#reset').click(function(){
    var confirm = confirm("This will reset everything, do you really want to continue?!");
if (confirm == true) {
    alert(); 
} 

  });
```

Any idea why above code doesn't work? I got an error of undefined is not a function.

Comment: for which line you getting this error. Also give some other name to variable confirm.

Comment: `var confirm = confirm("..` wont work. Assign a different variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the local variable `confirm`.

Since you have declared a local variable with name `confirm`, when you use `confirm()` in your function it will have the value `undefined` as it is no longer referring to the global confirm function.

Just rename the variable and it should be fine.

```
$('#reset').click(function () {
    var value = confirm("This will reset everything, do you really want to continue?!");
    if (value == true) {
        alert();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because after running this code once, `confirm` is not a function, but a boolean, in handler's function scope.

Change the local variable name to something else, like 'value' or 'confirmed'.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm is a function, please change the variable confirm in to something else.

```
var result = confirm("This will reset everything, do you really want to continue?!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try by changing the name of your variable "confirm" (var confirm). It is the keyword of javascript language.